# Unexpected error parsing Amazon Alexa Smart Home JSON schema

Tags: node.js, json, jsonschema, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to create some integration tests for an Alexa smart home skill back-end using [the validation schema Amazon provides](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-smarthome/blob/master/validation_schemas/alexa_smart_home_message_schema.json) but when I try to parse it using `JSON.parse` I get an error:

```js
> JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('alexa_smart_home_message_schema.json', 'utf-8'))
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 262146
```

This surprises me, as the file looks fine and no errors are reported when using it on https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ so it's surely valid JSON, so I'm really not sure what is going wrong here. Is there some gotcha with using `JSON.parse` on large files or something? The file is not huge, around 635 KiB.

Node.js version is 12.20.1

Comment: This would suggest you have a syntax error in your JSON file. Have you tried opening it in a language-aware editor such as VSCode? If the language mode is set to JSON (which it should be automatic when opening a JSON file), then it should highlight any errors.

Comment: A JSON Schema validator may not pick up errors relating to parsing. If you try a normal editor and still you have an issue, please paste your JSON in a gist or something to share here, or if it's not long, include it in your question.

Comment: Ah ok, I assumed that the validator would pick up any syntax errors and I was doing something wrong with the reading -- turns out it was indeed a syntax error in Amazon's schema! Many thanks :)

Comment: It's the dangling comma. Not allowed in JSON. I'm commenting on your github issue.

Comment: Feel free to join the JSON Schema slack server if you have questions which don't fit on StackOverflow =]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my assumption that Amazon's JSON was valid was incorrect, there's a syntax error in the schema.